# Appropriate Placement of Switch Statement for Login Redirection

Tags: php, mysql

Still an amateur when it comes to PHP. I am trying to setup login redirection for my some PHP code that I am using to log users into a system. As of right now, I have both the switch statement and the PHP completed, it's just meshing them together.

I have a user, password, groupID column in my table.

Thanks for your help!

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "dbname");
//"localhost", "userName" is username; "Password" is password; "dbName" is DB_Name;
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "MySql Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE UserName='$_POST[UserName]' && Password='$_POST[Password]' && GroupID='$_POST[GroupID]'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if ($count==1)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['UserName'] = $_POST['UserName'];
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $_POST['Password'];
    $_SESSION['GroupID'] = $_POST['GroupID'];
    //header("location: http://localhost/wordpress/test-page/");
    }
else
{
    echo "Invalid username or password";
    }   

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Switch Statement:

```
    <?php

$GroupID = $_POST['GroupID'];


switch($GroupID){
    case '1': 
        header("Location: http://localhost/wordpress/portal1/");
        } else
    case '2':
        header("Location: http://localhost/wordpress/portal2/");
    case '3':
    // If GroupID = 3 Redirect to correct page
        header("Location: http://localhost/wordpress/portal3/");
    default:
    // If GroupID does not match set user groups redirect to error page
        header("Location: couldNotDirect_ContactAdmin.html");
}
```

?>

Comment: um, you put it right where you've commented out the header... also, fix your SQL injection exploits

Comment: I sure hope you're not live or intended to go live with this and for so many reasons. Btw, you've an (unexplained) answer below. If that doesn't solve it, then guess what? Yeah... not enough code for the question. RTM on that case btw, which you obviously either didn't or figured you could just get rid of some important tidbits you may have found to be useless.

Comment: No, this is in a test environment.

@JeffPuckettII - I was intending to use a switch for this, not just a header to  redirect to one page...

Comment: @B.James I said put your switch right where you commented the header, just like demonstrated in pipsqeak's answer, not to uncomment the header.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "dbname");
//"localhost", "userName" is username; "Password" is password; "dbName" is DB_Name;
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "MySql Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE UserName='$_POST[UserName]' && Password='$_POST[Password]' && GroupID='$_POST[GroupID]'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if ($count==1)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['UserName'] = $_POST['UserName'];
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $_POST['Password'];
    $_SESSION['GroupID'] = $_POST['GroupID'];
    switch($_POST['GroupID']){
        case '1': 
            header("Location: http://localhost/wordpress/portal1/");
            break;
    case '2':
        header("Location: http://localhost/wordpress/portal2/");
        break;
    case '3':
    // If GroupID = 3 Redirect to correct page
        header("Location: http://localhost/wordpress/portal3/");
        break;
    default:
    // If GroupID does not match set user groups redirect to error page
        header("Location: couldNotDirect_ContactAdmin.html");
        break;`enter code here`
}
    }
else
{
    echo "Invalid username or password";
    }   

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @pipskweak! I will give this a shot and let you know!